# Integrating Django with a legacy database

Tags: django

o legacy db table information

```
MEM_ID  MEM_SQ  X_AUTH_USER X_AUTH_KEY  X_STORAGE_URL   ACCESSKEY
```

o models of my apps information
 that referred to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

migrate db

```
python manage.py migrate
```

models of my apps

```
 class SsAuthList(models.Model):
    mem_id = models.CharField(db_column='MEM_ID', max_length=62, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    mem_sq = models.CharField(db_column='MEM_SQ', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    x_auth_user = models.CharField(db_column='X_AUTH_USER', max_length=59, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    x_auth_key = models.CharField(db_column='X_AUTH_KEY', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    x_storage_url = models.CharField(db_column='X_STORAGE_URL', max_length=71, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    accesskey = models.CharField(db_column='ACCESSKEY', max_length=62, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

checked admin web site. But is not information to db table 
(legacy db row is 500)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that you have lost the meta-class definition:

```
class SsAuthList(models.Model):
    mem_id = models.CharField(db_column='MEM_ID', max_length=62, blank=True, null=True)
    mem_sq = models.CharField(db_column='MEM_SQ', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    x_auth_user = models.CharField(db_column='X_AUTH_USER', max_length=59, blank=True, null=True)
    x_auth_key = models.CharField(db_column='X_AUTH_KEY', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    x_storage_url = models.CharField(db_column='X_STORAGE_URL', max_length=71, blank=True, null=True)
    accesskey = models.CharField(db_column='ACCESSKEY', max_length=62, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'TABLE_NAME'
```